# Run a VBA sub from command button in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I'm having trouble attaching a VBA macro to a form button in MS Access. I have my public sub Demo defined in a Module1 under VBA. In Access, I ensured macros are enabled because I can click in the VBA window and run my macro by pressing F5.

In Access, I created a new blank form (Ribbon > Create > Forms > Blank Form). On the form, I went into Design View. Then Ribbon > Design > Controls > Ensure "Use Control Wizards" is pressed.

Then I pressed Button and dropped a new command button onto my form. In the Command Button Wizard, I clicked Miscellaneous under Categories, and then Run Macro under Actions, and pressed Next.

I expected to see a list of modules or macros listed in the list on the following screen that prompts, "What macro would you like the command button to run?"

Instead, the list is empty.  Where do I find the macro to add to the command button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go into the Design View of your form.
2. Press the ALT key and the F11 key simultaneously, and you will see
   the VBA Code window.
3. Find your form and double-click it, which will bring up the code
   behind your form.

   Find your button, and put this piece of code in it:

   DoCmd.RunMacro "YourMacroName"

Obviously, replace "YourMacroName" with the name of your macro, but keep it inside the double quotes.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!! Alternatively, I also noticed I could right-click the button in Design view > Build Event > Code Builder. In the macro body, instead of DoCmd.RunMacro, I was able to call my method directly with Module1.Demo. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!